# Python script running from SCONS cannot access environment variables

Tags: python, environment-variables, scons

Inside of my scons script I execute another python script:

```
fs = env.Command('fs', None, 'python updatefs.py')
AlwaysBuild(fs)
Depends(fs,  main)
```

In python script I am trying to access an environment variable:

```
import os
mode = os.environ['PROC_MODE']
```

The variable was previously set up in the shell:

```
export PROC_MODE='some_mode'
```

Python complain:

```
KeyError: 'PROC_MODE'
```

What is the proper way to propagate environment to an external script?

Comment: As a workaround right now I am passing this variable as an argument to the script but, imho it is an ugly approach

Comment: I suspect env.Command is creating another instance of the shell.  If you have two instances of the shell (outside of py) can they access each other's environment variables.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in lightly in the FAQ:

[FAQ](http://scons.org/faq.html#Why_doesn.27t_SCons_find_my_compiler.2BAC8-linker.2BAC8-etc..3F_I_can_execute_it_just_fine_from_the_command_line.)

Basically SCons constructs a clean reproducible set of environment variables so that differences in any user's environment won't break a build.

So if you want to propagate a particular variable from your shell you can explicitly do it as such:

```
env['ENV']['MY_VARIABLE']=os.environ['MY_VARIABLE']
```

If you wanted to progagate all environment variables you'd do this:

```
env['ENV'] = os.environ
```

Where env is your Environment()

Comment: I have seen all those post and FAQ but, still it wasn't very clear for me how to do it going from scons to external script. Thanks. It works.